# Initialize instance variable in a mixin

Tags: python

I want to provide some functionality to classes using [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful). The functionality uses some additional per-object state. I was wondering what is the cleanest way to initialize this local state. Consider the example:

```
class Mixin:
    items = []
    def append(self, x):
        self.items.append(x)
    def display(self):
        print self.items

class Foo(object, Mixin): pass
class Bar(object, Mixin): pass

foo = Foo()
foo.append('foo')
foo.display()

>>> ['foo']

bar = Bar()
bar.append('bar')
bar.display()

>>> ['foo', 'bar']
```

Here, the state is `items` list. Initializing it in the Mixin body is obviously wrong. Normally, I would initialize it in `__init__`, but with Mixin I do not want to mess with `__init__`.

I could do the following:

```
class Mixin:
    items = None

def append(self, x):
    if self.items is None:
        self.items = []
    self.items.append(x)
```

But the condition is evaluated on each `append` and it does not seem to be the cleanest solution.

Any alternatives? Or maybe adding `__init__` to the mixin is The way?

(It is a separate question if using mixins is OK or not)

*Related*:

- [Initializing instance variables in Mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586051/initializing-instance-variables-in-mixins) for Ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose to put that in an `__init__()` of the Mixin.  What do you think is the disadvantage?

```
class Mixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items = []
```

I think this is right way to do it; all other (maybe working) solutions look like a hack to me.

Comment: Should Mixin be inherited from object?

Comment: I assume you mean whether `Mixin` should inherit `object`; I'm going to answer this.  Without the inheriting of `object`, the class will be an old-style class.  In order to use `super()` correctly, it should be a new-style class, so inherit `object`, yes.

Comment: You can omit the object in Python 3, but include it anyway, so your code will work on Python 2 as well.

Comment: Does the type of the mixin actually matter? It will never be instantiated itself and when mixed into a new-style class the class remains new-style.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is adding an `__init__` method and using `super()` in each of those methods to ensure every single one is called.

```
class Mixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.items = []
        super(Mixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def append(self, x):
        self.items.append(x)
    def display(self):
        print self.items
```

Comment: `super` needs the class to inherit `object` to work properly.

Comment: Ah, thanks Blubber.  Good to know.  On the other hand, this post isn't about Python3 in particular.

Comment: True, and in Python 3 you can add object, but it doesn't actually do anything, so it's a good idea to add it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's the old problem with the changing constructor signature.  *sigh* That has no good solution I know of.  One way I typically use is to let each constructor garble up all the parts of the input which it understands (it "consumes" them) and pass on only the ones it doesn't know of.  That way the `object`'s `__init__()` will receive an empty `kwargs` which it won't complain about.

Comment: Have a look at http://pastebin.com/MieUwp3p to see what I mean (in case it wasn't clear already).